# Deserializing XML that has <li></li>

Tags: c#, xml

I have an XML file that contains elements that have lists of items:

```
<recipe>
<title>Recipe 1</title>
<ingredients><li>eggs</li><li>milk</li><li>etc...</li></ingredients>
<instructions><li>break eggs</li><li>spill milk</li><li>enjoy!</li></ingredients>
</recipe>
```

I am using Visual Studio C# XmlReader.Deserialize() to deserialize the XML into a class that I would like to look like this:

```
public class recipe
{
string title;
string ingredients[];
string instructions[];
}
```

Where each element of ingredients and instructions would be the text between li tags.

Worse comes to worse, I would accept ingredients and instructions each being a single string that I could then parse out the li tags.

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Can you post your whole xml ?

Comment: Seems like you haven't tried anything before asking this question, since `string ingredients[];` is not a valid c# declaration.

Answer (score 2):

looks like you made a slight error in your code. you close instructions with /ingredients.

this should work to properly deserialize to a class

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class recipe
{

    private string titleField;

    private string[] ingredientsField;

    private string[] instructionsField;

    public string title
    {
        get
        {
            return this.titleField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.titleField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("li", IsNullable = false)]
    public string[] ingredients
    {
        get
        {
            return this.ingredientsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.ingredientsField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("li", IsNullable = false)]
    public string[] instructions
    {
        get
        {
            return this.instructionsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.instructionsField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should use auto-property instead of property with backing fields. See my [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27888054/1248177).

Comment: @aloisdg just for learning: is there a tangible reason or is it to keep the code concise?

Comment: To quote Jeff Atwood `The really important thing to take away here is to avoid writing code that doesn't matter. And property wrappers around public variables are the very essence of meaningless code.` [Read more here](http://blog.codinghorror.com/properties-vs-public-variables/).

Answer (score 1):

First you have an error, you should read the close-tag of `<instructions>`.

Well, your xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<recipe>
    <title>Recipe 1</title>
    <ingredients>
       <li>eggs</li>
       <li>milk</li>
       <li>etc...</li>
    </ingredients>
    <instructions>
       <li>break eggs</li>
       <li>spill milk</li>
       <li>enjoy!</li>
    </instructions>
</recipe>
```

You should use `property` for your class :

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public class recipe
{
    public string title { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("li", IsNullable = false)]
    public string[] ingredients { get; set; }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("li", IsNullable = false)]
    public string[] instructions { get; set; }
}
```

I use a [generator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh371548(v=vs.110).aspx) to build this class. The generator add some attributes to your properties. Learn about them [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83y7df3e(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you had an error in your xml, it should look like:

```
<recipe>
<title>Recipe 1</title>
<ingredients>
    <li>eggs</li><li>milk</li><li>etc...</li>
</ingredients>
<instructions>
    <li>break eggs</li><li>spill milk</li><li>enjoy!</li>
</instructions>
</recipe>
```

Also, your class is supposed to be:

```
[XmlRoot("recipe")]
public class Receipe
{
    [XmlElement("title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("ingredients")]
    [XmlArrayItem("li")]
    public string[] Ingridients { get; set; }

    [XmlArray("instructions")]
    [XmlArrayItem("li")]
    public string[] Instructions { get; set; }
}
```

And finally, code:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Receipe));
var reader = new StringReader(xml);
var receipe = (Receipe)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
reader.Close();
```